# Android ContentProvider find other URIs

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am writing an application that will query other application's ContentProviders.  I am running into a problem because I cannot get the other application's ContentProvider's URIs given its ProviderInfo.  So far, I have the following function that takes in a ProviderInfo object, but I cannot figure out how to find its available URIs to query. Calling provider.authority is not sufficient because it doesn't specify the suffix table name to query.  Other applications are able to do this, such as ContentProviderHelper (https://github.com/jenzz/ContentProviderHelper), but I can't quite find how they are doing it in their code.

Has anybody had any luck with this?

```
public String[] getContentProviderColumnNames(ProviderInfo provider){
    Uri u = Uri.parse("content://"+provider.authority);//How do i get the complete URI?

    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    //below fails of course because the URI is invalid
    Cursor c = resolver.query(u, null, null, null, null);

    //Todo: for each found uri (tablename), query it using getColumnName
    //Get column names
    int colCount = c.getColumnCount();
    String[] columnNames = new String[colCount];
    for (int i = 0; i<colCount; i++) {
        columnNames[i] = c.getColumnName(i);
    }
    return columnNames;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am writing an application that will query other application's ContentProviders.

That is unlikely to work well, since you know absolutely nothing about the other apps' providers. Any provider that you *could* access this way is indicative of a security flaw in the other app, as the provider should be defended by appropriate permissions.

> I am running into a problem because I cannot get the other application's ContentProvider's URIs given its ProviderInfo.

Correct. The valid `Uri` values are up to the implementation of the provider and are not discoverable.

> Other applications are able to do this, such as ContentProviderHelper (https://github.com/jenzz/ContentProviderHelper)

No, they are not. Mr. Driller's search mechanism is making guesses as to the `Uri` values, using the same basic algorithm as is in your code snippet in your question. There is no requirement that a provider use that `Uri` value, and I would expect that few will. The rest are [hard-coded](https://github.com/jenzz/ContentProviderHelper/blob/master/res/values/arrays.xml).

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the confusion I had with ContentProviderHelper.  My next comment would be about the Drozer vulnerability testing framework.  I assume that it must gather ContentProvider URIs via parsing dumpsys over ADB.  Nevertheless, you answered my question, thanks!

Comment: @behren: I have not poked at Drozer to see what it does. Certainly a sufficiently-powerful decompiler could infer the `Uri` structures that some `ContentProvider` implementations use, but on the whole it's an unbounded problem.